# how to have the journal name shown when I cite a paper in beamer?

Tags: beamer, citing

I am writing a `beamer` presentation and I would like citations to appear (in the text!) like

> [Doe et al., Journal of Latex Greatness, 2007]

Instead if I use only the `\cite{}` command (together with `apalike` bibliography style) I only get the author and date:

> [Doe et al., 2007]

Do you have any ideas? I use a large BiBTeX file that stores all the relevant information.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple to achieve with `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{journal,
author = {Author, A.},
title = {Title},
journal = {Journal Name},
volume = {1},
year = 2013,
}  
@book{book,
author = {Bauthor, B},
title = {Book Title},
year = 2012
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  [\mkbibbrackets]
  {\printfield{prenote}}
  {\printnames{labelname}
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\newunit{\addcomma}\printfield{journaltitle}}
    {}%
  \newunit{\addcomma}
  \printfield{labelyear}%
  }
  {\addsemicolon\addspace}
  {\printfield{postnote}}

\begin{document}



\begin{frame}\frametitle{Title}
\cite{journal}\\
\cite{book}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{References}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Run, `pdflatex filename`, `biber filename`, `pdflatex filename`.

Alternatively, if one prefers `bibtex` to `biber`, then add `backend=bibtex` to the options of `biblatex`, i.e., `\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`.

Caveat, the solution offers a simplified redefinition of `\cite` (it  should work for most normal/simple cases).